# Spring @Value annotation not working with mockito mock

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, mockito, spring-annotations

I am using spring `@Value` annotation and setting values for some fields in class `A`.

I am writing unit tests for this class `A`. In the test class, I am annotating the reference for class `A` with Mockito `@Spy`. I am setting the values as system properties and then invoking `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this).`

My expectation is the spied object will have the fields initialized with the values from system properties via `@Value` annotation. But this is not happening.

Please anybody could explain?

Comment: Code of the test please?

Comment: Hard to answer without seeing the relevant part of your code. Also are you using [Springockito](https://bitbucket.org/kubek2k/springockito/wiki/Home)?

Comment: You test is probably not loading the spring context and therefore has not had a chance to initialize the value.  Without the class code it is difficult to answer your question.

Answer (score 3):

I have a similar test and I'm using the following relevant code:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations="/context.xml")
public class ContextTest {

    private boolean started = false;

    @Spy
    @Autowired
    private Baz baz;

    @Before
    public void before() {
        if (!started) {
            MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
            started = true;
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void spy() {
        Assert.assertEquals("value", baz.getProperty());
        Mockito.verify(baz).getProperty();
    }

}
```

Basically it will let spring process the test annotations (due to `SpringJUnitRunner`) and afterwards let Mockito process them (explicitly invoked `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(instanceOfTestClass)`).

---

**Other files to have a complete test**

simple `Baz.java` spring class:

```
package foo.bar;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;

public class Baz {

    @Value("${property:test}")
    private String property;

    public String getProperty() {
        return property;
    }

    public void setProperty(String property) {
        this.property = property;
    }

}
```

the `context.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="location">
            <value>my.properties</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="baz" class="foo.bar.Baz" />

</beans>
```

`my.property` file:

```
property=value
```

and the maven (`pom.xml`) file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>spring-test</groupId>
    <artifactId>my.spring.test</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.5</version>
                    <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

the file structure is:

```
+ spring-test
  - pom.xml
  + src/main/java
      + foo.bar
         - Baz.java
  + src/main/resources
      - context.xml
      - my.properties
  + src/test/java
      + foo.bar
         - ContextTest.java
```

Answer (score 3):

Mockito **is not** Spring aware! And will never be! You'll always have to init these kind of injection yourself as it is not pure java.

However you can take a look at [**springockito**](https://bitbucket.org/kubek2k/springockito/wiki/Home), it is a spring extension that enable some interesting usage of Mockito with Spring. But you'll have to create a Spring context for the test.

Note that using a spring context in a JUnit test is like crafting an integration test.